# Display Portfolio Posts only from certain category with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Good Day.

I am using a theme that has a Portfolio. The portfolio currently displays all categories listed. How can I change it to display only certain categories ie. Design and Images?

Here is the code of the Portfolio Template Page

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
global $wp_query;
$post = $wp_query->post;
$gogo_select_portfolio_cat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_select_portfolio_cat', true);
$gogo_portfolio_items_order = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_portfolio_items_order', true);
$gogo_portfolio_text_no_posts = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_portfolio_text_no_posts', true);
$gogo_select_portfolio_template = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_select_portfolio_template', true);
$gogo_select_portfolio_sidebar_position = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_select_portfolio_sidebar_position', true);
?>

<div class="block clearfix">

<header class="box-headline">
    <h4 class="main-headline"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
</header>

<?php if ($gogo_select_portfolio_template=='portfolio-fourthcol') { 
    load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/lib/includes/portfolio/portfolio-4col.php');
} ?>

<?php if ($gogo_select_portfolio_template=='portfolio-threecol') { 
    load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/lib/includes/portfolio/portfolio-3col.php');
} ?>

<?php if ($gogo_select_portfolio_template=='portfolio-twocol') { 
    load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/lib/includes/portfolio/portfolio-2col.php');
} ?>

</div>

<?php get_footer();?>.
```

**Portfolio-4col.php content:**

```
<ul id="filterOptions" class="horizontal" data-option-key="filter">
    <li><a class="selected" href="#filter" data-option-value="*">Show all</a></li>
    <?php
    $categories=  get_categories('taxonomy=portfolio_cat&title_li='); 
    foreach ($categories as $category){ ?>
    <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".<?php echo $category->slug;?>" title="Filter by <?php echo $category->name;?>"><?php echo $category->name;?></a></li>
    <?php }?> 
</ul>

<ul class="isotope-holder horizontal four-columns">
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( array( 
                     'post_type' => 'portfolio', 
                     'posts_per_page' => -1,
                     'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
                     )
              );
$postcount = 0;
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $postcount++;?>

<!--Retrieve posts meta from custom post types -->
<?php
$gogo_portfolio_short_desc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_portfolio_short_desc', true);
$gogo_portfolio_video_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_portfolio_video_url', true);
$gogo_portfolio_custom_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_portfolio_custom_link', true);
$gogo_portfolio_display_image_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_portfolio_display_image_link', true);
$gogo_portfolio_display_article_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_portfolio_display_article_link', true);
$gogo_portfolio_display_external_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_portfolio_display_external_link', true); ?>

<li class="element <?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'portfolio_cat'); foreach ($terms as $term) {  echo ' ' .$term->slug. ' '; } ?>">
<div class="view view-sixth">
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
<figure>
<?php $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail[0].'&amp;w=218&amp;h=200&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;s=1" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';?>
</figure>
<?php } ?>

<div class="mask">
        <header class="box-headline">
            <?php echo '<h4><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'; echo ''.get_the_title().''; echo '</a></h4>'; ?>
        </header>
    <div class="content">
        <p><?php echo $gogo_portfolio_short_desc; ?></p>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="info"><span>Read More &raquo;</span></a>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {

var $jcontainer = $j('ul.isotope-holder');

$jcontainer.isotope({
  itemSelector : '.element',
  resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
  // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
  masonry: { columnWidth: $jcontainer.width() / 4 }
});

// update columnWidth on window resize
$j(window).smartresize(function(){
  $jcontainer.isotope({
    // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
    masonry: { columnWidth: $jcontainer.width() / 4}
  });
});

var $joptionSets = $j('#filterOptions'),
    $joptionLinks = $joptionSets.find('a');

$joptionLinks.click(function(){
  var $jthis = $j(this);
  // don't proceed if already selected
  if ( $jthis.hasClass('selected') ) {
    return false;
  }
  var $joptionSet = $jthis.parents('#filterOptions');
  $joptionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $jthis.addClass('selected');

  // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
  var options = {},
      key = $joptionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
      value = $jthis.attr('data-option-value');
  // parse 'false' as false boolean
  value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
  options[ key ] = value;
  if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
    // changes in layout modes need extra logic
    changeLayoutMode( $jthis, options )
  } else {
    // otherwise, apply new options
    $jcontainer.isotope( options );
  }

  return false;
});
});

</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: The information we need to fix this problem is likely in `portfolio-2col.php`, `3col.php` or `4col.php`

Comment: Just one should get us started...

Answer (score 0):

edit: after seeing the portfolio pages. you can change the query_post command according your needs.

```
query_posts( 'cat=id' );
```

where 'id' is the number id of your category.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#All_Posts_in_a_Category for more info.

Answer (score 0):

To only show one category instead of all of them:

Replace this:

```
$categories =  get_categories('taxonomy=portfolio_cat&title_li=');
```

with this:

```
$categories[] = get_category('cat=4'); // replace 4 with category ID you're looking for
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I replaced it just as you said but nothing changed except that now it shows all the categories' images, and it does not give me the option on top to toggle between different categories anymore.

Comment: Hm, what was your end goal? What are you trying to do?

Comment: G look at the following site: http://http-solutions.com/themes/quiven/?page_id=1240 . You will see categories listed. Currently it shows all the available cats. I only want it to show cat 'Logo'. How would I do that?

Comment: Can you login to wordpress? Check out your portfolios tab.

Comment: You see, basically what i want to do is to have 2 Wordpress pages, each one showing the 4-col portfolio each showing only certain categories. Currently each page with the porfolio template will show all available categories

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can change which ones are showing from the dashboard. Do your portfolios have categories listed?

Comment: yes it does. But remember now, If i disable some of the categories, I won;t be able to show them in another portfolio post...

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution & it worked for me.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'portfolio-cats' => 'YOUT PORTFOLIO CATEGORY SLUG',
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```